# Rails nested html helper

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, helper

I'm creating a helper in my rails app where I create a navigation link.
Now I want to add an caret to this link so I can get a nice arrow at the end.

My html should look like this:

```
<li class='dropdown'>
   <a class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown' href='#'
       Dropdown
       <b class='caret'></b>
   </a>
```

Now I got my helpers setup like this:

```
  content_tag(:li, class: 'active dropdown') do
    link_to( text, link, class: 'dropdown-toggle' ) do
      content_tag(:b, class: 'caret')
    end
  end
```

But when I do this I got this error message:

```
undefined method `stringify_keys' for "/":String
```

I also want to add some item to my dropdown so I need to nested some more but I don't know how. Is there anybody who could help me and point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You’re passing a block to `link_to` so you shouldn’t pass it link text, as shown [in the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to). Try this:

```
content_tag(:li, class: 'active dropdown') do
  link_to(link, class: 'dropdown-toggle' ) do
    "#{text}#{content_tag(:b, "", class: 'caret')}".html_safe
  end
end
```

Comment: Almost there but now it escapes the html for the caret, I already tried some combination with html_safe but without the right result. Any other suggestions ?

Comment: Oh yes. `content_tag` needs the tag content as its second parameter if there’s no block, so I added an empty string. As an aside, have you considered using an `:after` CSS selector to attach your arrow?